# NetLogo Behaviourspace Experiment output for every tick

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to run experiments for a model of mine. I need it to output certain variable values for every tick but when I run the experiment I only get the values of either tick = 0 or the values at the end of the simulation. I need the values for every tick, anyone knows how this can be done in the NetLogo behaviour space experiments? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

When you setup an experiment, there is a checkbox for saving the "reports" of a reporter at every step:

[image: Checkbox for measuring at every step]

When I setup this experiment for the `Wolf Sheep Predation` Model from the Models Library, it outputs the `count turtles` for every tick.

[image: Full BehaviorSpaceScreen for]

Comment: Hi, when I do this I only get outputs for tick = 0, that's the problem im facing. When I print the variable in my code i do see the value every tick so my variable is not the problem...

Comment: Then, I'm clueless, sorry!